# Solve: $\int\frac{1}{3x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Solve: $$\int\frac{1}{3x}dx$$

The answer in the back of the book is: $$\frac{1}{3}\log_e|x|+c$$

I get this result when I remove the constant $\frac{1}{3}$ from the integral at the start and substitute u for x at the beginning. Also by differentiating the result I can return to the initial integral.

But if at the beginning I do not remove the constant $\frac{1}{3}$from the integral and substitute $u$ for $3x$ I get a different result. $$\frac{1}{3} \log_e |3x| +c$$ Differentiating this does not bring me back to the initial integral.

What is wrong with substituting $u$ for $3x$ here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\frac13\log|3x|+C=\frac13\log|x|+\frac13\log(3)+C=\frac13\log|x|+C'$

Comment: So given the initial integral both answers are correct?

Comment: @Derek yup $\qquad$

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. Thanks